# unable to read hash from json file

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-3.8, sha512

This is part of my code for creating and logging into accounts in my game, I have cut out the acquisition of the username and password from the user and have just kept the password hashing and file read/writing

```
##CREATE ACCOUNT##
    
    #Encrypt password
    newPswdEnc = hashlib.sha512()
    newPswd = bytes(newPswd, "ascii")
    newPswdEnc.update(newPswd)
    newPswdEnc = str(newPswdEnc.digest()).replace("\\", ".")
    
    #Assemble and place in file       
    newLogin = {"Username":newUsnm,"Pswd":newPswdEnc,"Highscore":0}
    
    with open("Users.json", "r+") as file:
         data = json.load(file)
    
         ##DOES SOME EXTRA VALIDATION TO PREVENT DUPLICATE USERNAMES##
    
         data["Logins"].append(newLogin)
         
    with open("Users.json", "w+") as file:
         json.dump(data. file, indent = 5)
    
##LOGIN##
    
    #Encrypt password
    pswdEnc = hashlib.sha512()
    pswd = bytes(pswd, "ascii")
    pswdEnc.update(pswd)
    pswdEnc = str(pswdEnc.digest()).replace("\\", ".")
    
    #CHECK USERNAME AND PASSWORD
    with open("Users.json", "r") as file:
         data = json.load(file)
    
    for i in range(0, len(data["Logins"])):
         if data["Logins"][i]["Username"] == usnm and data["Logins"][i]["Pswd"] == pswd:
              loggedIn = True

##Logins.json##
{
     "Logins": [
          {
               "Username": "ADMIN",
               "Pswd": b'#.x8b.x90.xe6.xe28-.xda.xfa.xdc5&k/.xa9.xa3q.xfb9b.xb6u.xcc.xab.x1bU82.x1fF.x90p.xd0.xf3v/).xb2.x1a.xc7.xadw..xb6.xbd).x9d.t.xf8.xe7]8.xed.x8bpg.x96]]_&.xeb.xc3.xf5',
               "Highscore": 0
          }
     ],
}
```

When attempting to sign in with the correct password I get this error:
Expecting value: line 5 column 24 (char 90)
which appears to be the b character at the start of the hash

Answer (score 0):

Problem with reading was solved by removing my filter for backslashes however I am now experiencing issues with the password comparison as whilst in another program I have put both hashes in variables and validated them. This program is refusing to do so.

Comment: problem solved, was comparing with the unhashed password